# What is wrong with my program? Amicable program

Tags: python

Question 3: Amicable
Implement a function amicable that takes a positive integer n. It returns the smallest amicable number greater than n.

Two different numbers are both amicable if the sum of the proper divisors of each is equal to the other. Any number that's part of such a pair is an amicable number.

```
def abundant(n):
    while n > 0:
        a = n
        k = n
        y = 0
        total = 0
        while k > y or n == 0:
            if n % k == 0:
                y = n // k
                if k != n:
                    total = total + k + y
                if k == y:
                    total = total - y
            k -=1
        total = total + 1
        print(total)
        def abundant2(n):
            b = n
            x = n
            y = 0
            total2 = 0
            while x > y or n == 0:
                if n % x == 0:
                    y = n // x
                    if x != n:
                        total2 = total2 + x + y
                    if x == y:
                        total2 = total2 - y
                x -=1
            total2 = total2 + 1
            print(total2)
            if total == b and total2 == a:
                print('Amicable!')
                amicable_numbers2 = int(total2)
                amicable_numbers = int(total)
            else:
                print('Nope')
        return abundant2
        n += 1


def amicable(n):
        """Return the smallest amicable number greater than positive integer n.

    Every amicable number x has a buddy y different from x, such that
    the sum of the proper divisors of x equals y, and
    the sum of the proper divisors of y equals x.

    For example, 220 and 284 are both amicable because
    1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10 + 11 + 20 + 22 + 44 + 55 + 110 is 284, and
    1 + 2 + 4 + 71 + 142 is 220

    >>> amicable(5)
    220
    >>> amicable(220)
    284
    >>> amicable(284)
    1184
    >>> r = amicable(5000)
    >>> r
    5020


    """
    nums = [amicable_numbers2, amicable_numbers]
    nums2 = [n for n in nums if n >= amicable_numbers2 and n <= amicable_numbers]
    return nums2 
    # return a value that is less than amicable_numbers2 and less than amicable_numbers???
```

Comment: how do I fix the format?

Comment: Shouldn't `amicable(5)` return `None` (since there is no number amicable with a prime)?

Comment: there is a {} symbol when you edit.
select the portion of your answer/question that you want to mark as code, and click on the button.

You may also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
Welcome to Stackoverflow